# Identify ENDIF for correspoding IF in a string

Tags: python

I get a small code in the form of a string.

```
"IF 'Physics'
 then
   'Passed in physics'
 else IF 'Chemistry'
 then 
    'Passed in Chemistry'
 ENDIF
```

ENDIF".

I need to break this string into multiple values based on the IF and ENDIF.
My output should be

1) IF 'Physics' then 'Passed in Physics'

2) IF 'Chemistry' then 'Passed in Chemistry'.

The string which I get will have nested IF, so need to identify and break it into multiple values.

Thank you
Venkat

Comment: I think usually the best is to build a small *parser* for this (from a *context-free* grammar).

Comment: Sheesh... Formatted code please!!

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is your question? Do you expect us to just provide you with the Python code with the functionality you described? What have you tried so far, and why hasn't it worked?

Comment: I don't need python code. I need guidance to start with. With the guidance, I will write the code.

Comment: Hi Church,Here is the formatted code... IF 'Pyhsics' 
  'Passed in physics'
else
  IF 'Chemistry'
    IF 'Practicals'
    'Passed in Chemistry'
 else
     'Filed in Chemistry'  
 ENDIF
  else
    'Passed in all'
  ENDIF 
ENDIF

Comment: Need your suggestion on how to write code in python for this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to use if statement in python:[if statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements)

If you need to convert a String into if-else statement, learn how to use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regex)

so first put your string into a variable like **var**
var should contains a line break like "\n", thus

```
var = var.replace("\n","").replace("else","\n").replace("ENDIF",".")
```